# Showing the value in terms array Word Press PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Having a hard time with some code. Perhaps someone can shine a light. I have the following code:

```
<?php  
    $reltag1=get_field('related_tag_1');
?>
```

This works nice. $reltag1 is being filled with `cow, winter`. But I want to show the contents in this code in the 'terms' line:

```
<?php
                 $args = array('post_type' => 'things', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'tax_query'  => array(
                                                                            array(
                                                                                'taxonomy'  => 'tags',
                                                                                'field'     => 'slug',
                                                                                'operator'  => 'AND',
                                                                                'terms'     =>  array( --- HERE OUT OUTPUT FROM $reltag1 --- ),
                                                                                
                                                                            ),
                                                                        ),);
```

Can anyone tell me how this can be done?
The right output needs to be: `'terms'     =>  array( cow, winter ),`

Comment: https://php.net/explode - you can use the explode function to turn a string into an array  based on a delimiter. please do some research before contributing. there is likely much more material related to this on site already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deed a lot of searching but couldn't find the right code. I am not an experienced programmer but I have some knowledge. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: What about `explode(', ', get_field('related_tag_1'))` ? check with the docs what it does, then put it at the place you already point to.

Comment: Got it working now! Thanks! Makes more sense now.